# Android Studio is not working and Freezed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not getting any option to start studio. Previously it was working
File, Edit Nothing is working. I am closing studion by task manager(Windows)
Android Studio 2.2.2

[image]

Comment: Nothing we can do for this issue. Make sure that you have at least 4gb ram. And restart your computer and try again

Comment: go to here in your PC. `C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudioPreview2.0` and remove `Cache` and Restart again the `Android Studio`.